# Failed installation of Bio::Grep on Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: perl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bioperl

I have installed bioperl on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 with `sudo apt-get install bioperl bioperl-run`. I tried to install Bio::Grep with cpanm but it failed. From `build.log` file it seems that something fails during testing:

```
# 
# *****************************************************************************
# * Bioperl    : FOUND                                                        *
# * Bioperl-run: FOUND                                                        *
# * Backend    : No backend found in path. You should install the back-ends   *
# *              before running these tests. This way you make sure that the  *
# *              parsers work with your installed version of the back-end.    *
# * EMBOSS     : FOUND                                                        *
# *****************************************************************************
t/00.checkprereq.t ............ ok

#   Failed test 'use Bio::Grep::Backend::Agrep;'
#   at t/00.load.t line 14.
#     Tried to use 'Bio::Grep::Backend::Agrep'.
#     Error:  UNIVERSAL does not export anything at ...
...

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/00.load.t                 (Wstat: 1280 Tests: 12 Failed: 5)
  Failed tests:  3-7
  Non-zero exit status: 5
t/10.backends.all.t         (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 133 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 344 tests but ran 133.
t/11.backends.guugle.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 0 tests but ran 1.
t/11.backends.re.t          (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 30 tests but ran 1.
t/20.filter.t               (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 17 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 46 tests but ran 17.
t/30.features.alignments.t  (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 50 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 108 tests but ran 50.
t/30.features.updownstream.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 16 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 46 tests but ran 16.
t/40.utils.t                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 30 tests but ran 1.
t/50.synopsis.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 9 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  6-7
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=13, Tests=242, 10 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr  0.19 sys +  2.33 cusr  5.13 csys =  7.76 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 9/13 test programs. 8/242 subtests failed.
-> FAIL Installing Bio::Grep failed
```

It seems that someone created ticket and encountered similar [problem](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=124639) before but I did not find a solution.

Comment: The output from `cpanm` says: *"No backend found in path. You should install the back-ends  before running these tests"* Have you tried to install the backends?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, That is not the issue here. A change to Perl broke the module. The lack of back ends presumably makes most of the tests useless, and maybe the module itself, but that's unrelated. However, it probably mean it's best to install the back end module that's intended to be used before installing Bio::Grep.

Comment: Note that this is unrelated to WSL.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is simple: Remove the `use UNIVERSAL ...;` line.

```sh
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/L/LI/LIMAONE/Bio-Grep-v0.10.6.tar.gz
tar xvzf Bio-Grep-v0.10.6.tar.gz
cd Bio-Grep-v0.10.6
perl -pe's/^(?=use UNIVERSAL)/#/' -i~ lib/Bio/Grep/Backend/BackendI.pm
perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install
```